# How do xlrd, xlwt, xlutils work with Excel in the low level?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

They are all open source Python packages to control Excel (see [python-excel](http://www.python-excel.org/)). I am still trying to understand their code. If anyone could give a hint, do how they connect in a low lever to Excel? Via xml, Excel API, or some other basic Python packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are talking about reading and writing XLS files, basically `xlrd` and `xlwt` follow the [OpenOffice.org document/specification](http://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf) describing Excel's format and *BIFF* *(Binary Interchange File Format)* records to read and write XLS files. If you would inspect the [`xlwt` source code](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/), you would find it manipulates the BIFF records for everything needs to be written: creating workbook, worksheets, writing data, formatting, alignment etc.

With [XLSX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181(v=office.12).aspx) the story is a bit different. To read XLSX `xlrd` relies on the [openxmlformats XML schemas](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/xlsx.py#L104) and [use built into Python ElementTree XML parsers](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/xlsx.py#L24) (`cElementTree` if available, otherwise  `ElementTree`) to parse the XLSX file which is, to simplify, a zip archive containing XML files inside. Here is a good overview of what is inside the archive:

- [Anatomy of OOXML - xlsx](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php)

I would also recommend studying the [`xlsxwriter` module](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) - from my point of view, the package is much better documented and [the code](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter) is much more cleaner and readable than `xlwt` or `xlrd`.